# How to query for relations that are empty?

Tags: objectbox

I have two classes with one-to-many relation:

```dart
@Entity()
class Lesson {
  final course = ToOne<Course>();
}


@Entity()
class Course {
  @Backlink('course')
  final lessons = ToMany<Lesson>();
}
```

I want to query for all lessons that does not belong to any course. Below does not work:

```dart
final qb = _box.query(Lesson_.course.isNull());
```

And the reason is explained in this [issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/732).

So I have to do this:

```dart
final qb = _box.query(Lesson_.course.equals(0));
```

Is there a better or a recommended way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for ObjectBox for Dart adding an equals 0 condition on the ToOne is the way to find objects without a ToOne target:

```
final noToOneTargetQuery = box.query(Entity_.toOne.equals(0)).build();
```

See [ObjectBox for Dart test code](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/adae4fb772291d4ec831c59b3ef4c071a2cee1ba/objectbox/test/relations_test.dart#L119-L124) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this feels rather unnatural. Maybe I should raise an issue?